# Continous uniform variable and a dependent discrete bernoulli variable

Tags: probability

Let $X\sim\text{Uniform}(\left[2,4\right])$, and $Y\sim\text{Ber}\left(\frac{1}{X}\right)$, I wonder how I can work with these variables (mainly with Y), let's say I want to calculate
$$
P\left(Y=1\right)
$$
My intuition is that I can calculate this value using integraion (something like extending the law of total probability):
$$
P\left(Y=1\right)=\int^4_2\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{x}dx=0.5\left[\ln\left(x\right)\right]_{2}^{4}=\frac{\ln\left(4\right)-\ln\left(2\right)}{2}
$$
And it looks correct (is it?), but I am not sure this is correct, and if it is correct, why is it.

Another (very similar) problem (and a solution) I though of is
$$
P\left(Y=1\wedge X\in\left[3,4\right]\right)=\int_{3}^{4}\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{x}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{3}^{4}\frac{1}{x}dx=\frac{1}{2}\left[\ln\left(x\right)\right]_{3}^{4}=\frac{\ln\left(4\right)-\ln\left(3\right)}{2}
$$

If my solutions are correct, what is the reasoning for their correctness? Is there another way to get to them (in the second one, maybe Bayes?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If my solutions are correct, what is the reasoning for their correctness?

Your first solution is correct and here is the explanation you asked for:

To be precise your $Y$ is a conditional rv, thus you have

$$\left(Y|X=x\right) \sim B\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

First observe that in a Bernulli model,

$$\mathbb{P}[Y=1]=\mathbb{E}[Y]$$

now using Conditional expectation's properties you get

$$\mathbb{E}[Y]=\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}[Y|X]\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{x}\right]=\int_2^4 \frac{1}{2x}dx=\frac{\log 4-\log 2}{2}$$

At present I did not check you second one

Comment: I am not sure I understand your notaiton. What does $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X]]$ mean? Isn't $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Z]]$ always equal to $\mathbb{E}[Z]$ (as the inner expectation is just a constant real number)?

Comment: @JoeMcCarthy the inner expectation is not a number but a function of the conditioning rv $X$ thus it is again a rv

Comment: @JoeMcCarthy : I checked you second solution an it results correct to me